# HTML Email - Coloring one part of link

Tags: html, css, email

Is it possible, when using HTML in an email, to color just part of a link a certain color?

I've tried:

```
<a href=""><span style="color: #AB2328 !important;">red part of link</span> normal part</a>
```

...I know it'd be possible if I split up the links but I'm trying to keep it together as one.

Comment: What you have should work fine.

Comment: Your code doesn't work? I don't think there is another way of doing it.

Comment: What you tried works. http://jsfiddle.net/tg9waLd1/

Comment: You don't need the `!important` as inline styles are always applied with a higher priority than a stylesheet or default styles.

Comment: no need to use     !important     in your code.

Comment: So can you tell us in which situations this fails to work? I mean, apart from when the default color for links is #AB2328.

Comment: This isn't "splitting up the link" at all. The hyperlink is still intact as a single item. What you have is the best, and possibly the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work, just take out !important

```
<a href=""><span style="color: #AB2328;">red part of link</span> normal part</a>
```